# How can I edit the VBA script to save to specific folder depending on the slicer selected

Tags: excel, vba, automation, slicers

I have developed a Dashboard which changes based on 2 slicers: Department and Employee.

My ultimate goal is for the attached code to run on the selected department's in the slicer and the 2nd slicer will have all the employees selected, then the code will loop through each employee and print to the PDF to save each one in in their perspective department folder.

The folder will have the department names as the folder name, so I am thinking along the lines of an = operator of some sort. I pulled this code from another user.

```
*The below VBA code goes through and selects all and places it in the folder. Is there a way to have 
 the PDF file save depending department or the first slicer. 
 
Private Sub PowerPivotLoopSlicerSimplePrintoPDF()
Dim SC As SlicerCache
Dim SL As SlicerCacheLevel
Dim SI As SlicerItem
Set SC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Employee") 'Add slicer name between " "
Set SL = SC.SlicerCacheLevels(1)
'c(ounter) is set to 1, ready to begin
c = 1
'Repeat the a loop until number of prints exceeds number of items in slicer
Do While c <= SC.SlicerCacheLevels.Item.Count + 1
'This makes sure that SI is the correct slicer. Needed for corrent file name.
For Each SI In SL.SlicerItems
    If SI.Selected = True Then
    SlicerverdiIndex = c
Exit For
    End If
Next SI

'PRINT CODE
Dim FName           As String
Dim FPath           As String
'Define file path for printed file storage
FPath = "C:\prchica\Desktop\Scorecard\PDF files"   'Choose your filepath
FName = SI.SourceName
'Define WHAT to print and how to build file name
 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
FPath & "\" & FName & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
False, From:=1, To:=1
'PRINT CODE FINISHED
'Sets the slicer to the last item in the list
If SlicerverdiIndex = 1 Then
SlicerverdiIndex = SC.SlicerCacheLevels.Item.Count + 1
End If
SC.VisibleSlicerItemsList = SL.SlicerItems(SlicerverdiIndex - 1).Name
'Adds 1 to the counter, will loop until end of slicer has been reached.
c = c + 1
Loop
End Sub*
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: AMC - thank you, I will reword: I researched for code related to automatically saving an Excel sheet with charts to PDF, and then researched how to get it to loop through slicers. Found code ideas for that and implemented it, and it works. That code is appended to the original question, it saves each PDF by the name of each slicer. I need code ideas on using the Slicer 'A' to pull the first slicer buttons name to get to file path folder name and then loop through Slicer 'B's , and printoPDF and choose next field data in Slicer 'A', which opens Slicer 'B' and save to its perspective folder.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by _code ideas_, where are you stuck?

Comment: I was able to figure it out and modify the code!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add this to my code:

```
Dim SC As SlicerCache

Set SC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Department") 'Add slicer name between " "
Call ParseAndPrintSlicer(SC)

Set SC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Emplid") 'Add slicer name between " "
Call ParseAndPrintSlicer(SC)
```